# TextView won't clear for some Reason, Android

Tags: android, textview

I hope this isn't a stupid question. I'm having some trouble clearing a TextView. I've looked around and everyone keeps saying use: textView.setText(""); in onCreate but doesn't seem to work for some reason. Basically, my app just accepts a number from an editText then runs the Fibonacci sequence (when a button is clicked) and displays the result in a textView. Well, the sequence displays fine but I want the textview to clear every time I click the button - so far it just keeps adding more text to what's already there.

Am I placing textView.setText(""); in the wrong location? Or am I just missing some other concept? (I also tried placing it from my OnClick - that didn't work either).

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// primary widgets
private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private Button button1;

static ArrayList<Integer> fibList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    //Attempt to clear TextView
    textView.setText("");

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String input = editText.getText().toString();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int tmp = 0;

            // confirm input
            if (number < 20) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You entered: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
                    fibList.add(fib(i));

                    // sum even numbers
                    if (fib(i) % 2 == 0) {
                        tmp += fib(i);

                    }

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Number is too Large: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            String array = fibList.toString();
            textView.setText(array);

        }

    });

}

// run fibonacci sequence
public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You should add `textView.setText("");` inside `onClick(View v)`

Comment: @dave Just wodered if you have tried my answer, I see you tried the others.

Comment: I did the problem was a combination of clearing my array list then clearing the textView. Thanks.

Comment: please note that on samsung galaxy one textView's inputType fields must be set (i set the inputType = text) to do setText("") or setText(null)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `TextView` to clear on each button click then the `.setText` must go in you `onClick`. The reason you would put the `.setText` in your `onCreate` is to clear the text as soon as your activity is created, but you do not have anything to clear just yet since your button has not yet been pushed so `setText` will do nothing. Also, since your `onCreate` will only run once for your activity, it will never go back to the `setText` again. Try the following:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// primary widgets
private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private Button button1;

static ArrayList<Integer> fibList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textView.setText(""); //Clear the TextView
            fibList.clear(); //Clear your array list before adding new elements

            String input = editText.getText().toString();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int tmp = 0;

            // confirm input
            if (number < 20) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You entered: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
                    fibList.add(fib(i));

                    // sum even numbers
                    if (fib(i) % 2 == 0) {
                        tmp += fib(i);

                    }

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Number is too Large: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            String array = fibList.toString();
            textView.setText(array);

        }

    });

}

// run fibonacci sequence
public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to clear textView on Button click event before adding new results to it.do it as:

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText("");  //<<<<<< clear TextView on Button Click
        .....
```

Comment: I just tried it. Nothing. It appears that it continues to add to my array list. I tried doing fibList.clear(). A log statement states that is in fact clear but the text view keeps adding to it for some reason.

Comment: Ok Solved my own problem. I had to initialize a string variable to "", then set the textView to it before building the array list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more likely in fibList that is not being cleared

Comment: I just tried using fibList.clear() at onClick - didn't work. Also moved textView.setText("") - also nothing.

Comment: Solved the problem. I had to initialize a string variable to "", then set the textView to it - while clearing the array. Thanks.